# How do I retrieve images from cloud firestore and firebase storage

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to access images through direct download link in firebase storage.But, I need to fetch it through the string url which has been stored in cloud firestore in a collection document (ImageLogs) and the  the key called ImageURL.

```
public class FaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView date, time, Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4;
    ImageView imageView;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    List<String> spinnerdatalist;
    TableLayout tableLayout;

    List<String> namelist = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri imageuri;
    Storage storageref;
    DocumentReference documentReference;
    String[] value;
    String[] temp1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_face);

        date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        Name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
        Name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name2);
        Name3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name3);
        Name4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name4);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        spinnerdatalist = new ArrayList<>();
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        documentReference = db.collection("ImageLogs").document();

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        DocumentReference user = db.collection("ImageLogs").document();

        user.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                    String imageURL = doc.getString("ImageURL");
                    Glide.with(FaceActivity.this)
                            .load((imageURL))
                            .into(imageView);
                }
            }
        });

}
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: What exactly isn't working the way you expect?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I don't get any error.the image is not loading in my image view

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very inefficient debugger, so please narrow the problem down locally. For example, if you set a breakpoint on ` Glide.with(` and run the code, does `imageURL` have the value you expect it to have? If you copy the value of `imageURL` and open that in a browser, does it show the image?